# Attachment not sent using Gmail and CDO in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel

I am trying to send the active worksheet via CDO and gmail to all people entered in some textboxes during the process of sending them away. I use the following code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim ProjectName As String
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant
Dim recipientsArray(1 To 10) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim qScore As String

recipientsArray(1) = TextBox1.Value
recipientsArray(2) = TextBox2.Value
recipientsArray(3) = TextBox3.Value
recipientsArray(4) = TextBox4.Value
recipientsArray(5) = TextBox5.Value
recipientsArray(6) = TextBox6.Value
recipientsArray(7) = TextBox7.Value
recipientsArray(8) = TextBox8.Value
recipientsArray(9) = TextBox11.Value
recipientsArray(10) = TextBox10.Value

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
End With

'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
If Sourcewb.Worksheets("Final Review Feedback").Range("B4").Value = "" Then
    TempFileName = "No project name"
Else
    TempFileName = Sourcewb.Worksheets("Final Review Feedback").Range("B2").Value & " " & Sourcewb.Worksheets("Final Review Feedback").Range("D4").Value
End If

If Sourcewb.Worksheets("Extraction").Range("C1").Value = "" Then
    ProjectName = "N/A"
Else
    ProjectName = Sourcewb.Worksheets("Extraction").Range("C1").Value
End If

If Sourcewb.Worksheets("Final Review Feedback").Range("D4").Value = 0 Then
    qScore = "QScore: N/A"
Else
    qScore = "QScore: " & Sourcewb.Worksheets("Final Review Feedback").Range("D4").Value
End If

Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mlsfinalreview@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "*******************"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(recipientsArray) To UBound(recipientsArray)
        If Not recipientsArray(i) = "" Then
            Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            With iMsg
                Set .Configuration = iConf
                .To = recipientsArray(i)
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Final Review Feedback: " & ProjectName & " " & qScore
                .TextBody = "Dear All," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "attached you will find the Final Review Feedback for " & ProjectName & "." _
                    & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Yours sincerely," & Chr(10) & Environ("Username")
                .from = """Final Review"" <mlsfinalreview@gmail.com>"
                .ReplyTo = "hr@marketlogicsoftware.com"
                .AddAttachment (TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Me.Hide

Sheet9.Range("N2").Value = "Awaiting Upload"

End Sub
```

Everything works fine (text, recipients, subject etc.) except for the attachments. They are not included in the email. As code I have tried `.Attachments.Add` and `.AddAttachments`. both with the same result.

I double-checked whether the filename was correct and it seems that it is fine. Does anyone have an idea why I send empty emails? Could it be a problem that I try to send the active workbook (while having it open and active)?

Comment: I would assume that there is no attachment. I see that you have an outer "with Destwb" and you attach to the mail "Destwb.fullname". Unfortunately one cannot see what type is Destwb, but it's like that you send some nonsense. My recommendation is: do not use "with", write the long form, then you get hopefully an error message

Comment: `Dim Destwb As Workbook`. Changed it to your recommendation - no error msg though,

Comment: For the protocol: My code does create the file and as far as I can tell, it has the right name and path. It just isn't attached to the mail. Or it is blocked by Google.

Comment: Tried many things. I believe Google blocks it.

Comment: you can reduce the security level on your account by "allow less secure apps", that helped me to send via Gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to get rid of the `With Destwb` and `End with`.

I deleted them and added two lines instead:

```
Destwb.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
Destwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Followed by the send-code. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've done in the past: copy the active worksheet, then send it via outlook.

```
Sub SendQuoteForm()
Dim Send As Integer
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
Dim LWorkbook As Workbook
Dim LFileName As String

Send = MsgBox("Please be sure that you are logged into Microsoft Outlook before sending your finsihed quote. Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Send Finished Quote?")
'I'm not sure if the whole gmail thing will work here, but it's a start
If Send = vbYes Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Copy

    Set LWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    LFileName = LWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill LFileName
    On Error GoTo 0
        LWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=LFileName

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    With oMail
        .To = "someone@something.com"
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .body = "blah blah blah"
        .Attachments.Add LWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
    End With

    LWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill LWorkbook.FullName
    LWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would love to do that, but I cannot use Outlook. The file might be used on a PC without Outlook (at least not set up).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the following line

```
 .AddAttachment "C:\Temp\Filename.xlsx"
```

or try

```
 .AddAttachment TempFilePath & "\" & TempFileName & FileExtStr
```

Comment: As I wrote, I used both notations. Why would this change anything?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst try adding full path to the file.

Comment: But then it's not generic anymore. I added some more code in my question.

Comment: I did add the code, I didn't add the password though ;-).

Comment: Actually, the port in the edit was wrong. I used 25. When using 587 nothing happens,

Comment: News. I used `Err.Description` to read the error message right after `.AddAttachments`. It shows "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".